# Should I cite a concept I have already cited earlier?

Tags: citations

I am writing a proposal for my PhD and it is majorly based on numerical modelling. I have cited the original model that I will be using earlier, and I think it is very clear throughout the proposal which model I am talking about. Should I still cite it again when I mention it later even though I think the running theme throughout is of the specific model I want to use? For example here:

> The experimental data thus acquired will then be used to construct the deformation history for the fractured rock, which will then be used to parametrise the numerical models.

I cite the models a few sections earlier, but the models are discussed throughout the whole text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to answer precisely without seeing your entire document.  In general, I'd say if it is very obvious what you are talking about, then you do not need to cite again.  The problem is that what is "obvious" to one person is not obvious to another.  Especially it can be hard for you to know if it is obvious or not because you are too close to it.  One suggest is to have a friend or other graduate student read the whole paper, and then ask them for an opinion.  Or, just err on the side of slightly more citations.

Comment: That is exactly what I am worried about, that I might be feeling it is obvious, but it might not be the case for others who read the proposal. I think getting a friend to read it is a good idea. I might still just cite the sources just to be sure, but the only problem is that I need to use APA citation style, and that has just been increasing the size of my paper too much, and I am very close to the maximum page count.

Comment: If the full citation is taking too much room, one option is to give the full citation the first time, and then give it a "nickname".  E.g. first time say "in this proposal we will use the model of Smith, Jones, Burns & White, Some Journal, 1987, hereafter referred to as the Smith model".  Then later instead of giving the full citation, you just say "Smith model".  This works best if the author Smith is at least somewhat well known in the field.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much. The author is relatively well known in the field so I should be fine. The model is developed fully in three papers, so it takes up a huge amount of space every time I cite it, which I feel is also very irritating to read